# Custom intellisense for a Qt-based dev tool

Tags: visual-studio, qt, autocomplete, qt-creator, intellisense

I am creating some custom tools to my Qt development toolkit. I have a need for somehow, in the way intellisense in Qt Creator and Visual Studio does, to get "metadata" of different available classes that are included in some inspected c++ file.

-How could I get such information?

-How does Qt Creator do this? Visual Studio?

-Should I use [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) for this?

-For Qt-specific intellisense, are there perhaps some relevant configuration/metadata files in the folder of the Qt installation?

Thanks.

Comment: I understand the downvote, as the question surely appears as ill-researched, however, I would appreciate some guidance as to in which direction to go in this issue. I am researching the subject at the same time.

Comment: It is done by parsing the code and building an object model. It is not simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Creator does it by maintaining a model of the code in the project you're working on. Historically, that model was populated by the custom C++ parser bundled with Qt Creator. Nowadays, Qt Creator defaults to a code model based on the clang C++ parser.

Good news: the source code to Qt Creator is available, and you can certainly access the code model from your own plugins.

You certainly don't need to mess with any object files; the C++ code model works without any need to actually build the project. It works on the source code, not binaries.

Comment: How complex it is to access that model? More specific directions will be more than welcome. Last time I needed that, it was easier to write a parser than plug into and using what Creator already had.

Comment: @ddriver "it was easier to write a parser" A C++ parser? I don't buy that, sorry. Just look around the code base, it's all there.

Comment: No need to buy when I ain't selling. It wasn't a C++ parse per-se, it is a generic parser that takes definitions in JSON format and creates an object tree. "It is all there" - nobody is saying it is not. The cure for cancer is "all there" in the human genome, but I don't see people curing it.

Comment: After a bit of research I was about to answer myself that it will probably be the easiest for me to use Clang to achieve what I need. I am looking into that, thanks.